# How to compare "text" (string) to be used as the condition for if statement

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

I want to ask the user if it wants "Classic Mode" or "Advanced Mode", I saved the answer in a variable and was trying to use it inside an IF statement, but it just doesn't work, let me show this part of my code for example:

```
int mode;

printf("\n Pick the desired mode: ");
    scanf("%i",&mode);

    if(mode=="Classic"){
        printf("It worked!");
        system("pause");
    }

    if(mode=="Advanced"){
        printf("It worked!");
        system("pause");
    }
```

It just goes straight to the end after the question and returns values close to 2 billion...

I thought I was getting error because is a value inside the variable, then I tried with a string, but I got the same result!

**@EDIT ==============================**

Ok guys, thanks for all the help, you guys are fast here in StackOverflow!

At the end it was the most idiot thing ever using `strcmp`, easy to understand and easy to use, fixed it all...
I had no idea about this one, if i knew it before, it would've saved a lot of time!

Comment: You are comparing an `int` with a `char*`. This is wrong. Make `mode` a character array, change the format specifier in `scanf` and then, Compare strings using `strcmp` or `strncmp` both of which is from  `string.h`.

Comment: heh? comapring `int` with `char *`? Read  basic C book first, sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-think about your approach, from the very beginning.

- **Approach 1**

  If you want to take a *characrter* based input from user, what you need is

  1. define an array.
  2. use `%s` with [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) to take input
  3. use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) to compare the input.

  *Note : This can be a little *tricky*, considering the *case* (upper and/or lower-only or mixed.) of input.*
- **Approach 2**

  If you want to *encode* the user input, i.e., want to take an integer equivalent for each *string*, you can

  1. define an `int` (as you did)
  2. `scanf()` with `%i`, again you did
  3. Compare with the predefined value for the strings using `==`, or, for a *longer* list of possible inputs, use a `switch` statement.

Comment: Thanks, but the same thing i asked Mihai, in this way if i wanted to add lots of possible answers, like for example: `if(mode=="Classic" || mode=="classic" || mode=="classiiiic"`
I need to create these all of these strings with possible answers right? So i can compare!?

Comment: @Skepller: For exactly that reason (misspellings), you should offer a menu with numbers indicating the choices (Approach 2), or perhaps work with the initial letter only. Checking for all *possible* misspellings is downright not possible. Integers would also allow you to use a `switch` instead of `if` (and hopefully, `else`).

Comment: @Skepller  First of all, you cannot compare _strings_ using `==`, secondly, if you follow my second approach, a `switch` case will be of great help.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Sorry, didn't add (at)OP. I meant misspellings in *his* user input. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar  Fine, fine. I was also just adding the `switch` statement usage into my answer. :)

Comment: Well, after using the second approach, i get a straight crash, any idea why?

Comment: @Skepller sorry, without seeing the code, no idea. :(

Comment: @Skepller there is no miracle-pill, you have to understand what you are doing in order to correct your code.

Comment: oh, nvm @SouravGhosh and @MihaiStancu, i was declaring as `char *mode;` like Mihai wrote below here, changing to `char mode[50]` fixed it, and it's working just fine, thanks for the help you guys!

Comment: @Skepller `char *mode` requires a `malloc` for the memory location of the data. `char mode[50]` doesn't it pushes 50bytes on the stack.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Yeah, you wrote that in your answer below :)
But there's no use of this in my program, it's very very simple, dinamic memory allocation is not need (at least for now)...

Answer (score 6):

### String comparison

Strings in `C` are handled using pointers to the first character in a sequence of characters (like an array) terminated by `\0` as the last character in the sequence. Comparing them requires the use of comparison functions such as `strcmp` otherwise you're comparing two pointers which (nearly) always differ.

They always differ because the string you "hardcoded" is a constant defined somewhere in your application's code while the string you're receiving from the user is malloc-ed at the time it's received and placed somewhere in the heap.

Constants are stored in one memory location, the heap is stored somewhere else. Those two pointers can never be the same.

On the other hand comparing two strings by value (comparing each character within the string) is done via `strcmp` or better yet `strncmp` which iterates on the characters in the array and compares each.

### Problem with the variable types

You currently define the `mode` variable as `int mode` which cannot hold a string value.

Also when retrieving the value from `scanf` you need to specify `%s` because it's retrieving a string not an integer.

When using `char *` the pointer needs to point to a preallocated piece of memory (using `malloc` for example).

### Alternatively -- integer comparison

You can however maintain you current structure but define some constants such as

```
static const CLASSIC_MODE = 1;
static const ADVANCED_MODE = 2;
```

And the user would need to input either 1 or 2 based on the displayed instructions / options list.

Then the comparison would be:

```
if (mode == CLASSIC_MODE) {
     /* classic mode */
}
```

Comment: Ok, comparing strings, so, if i wanted to add lots of possible answers, like for example: `if(mode=="Classic" || mode=="classic" || mode=="classiiiic"`
I need to create these 3 strings to compare to?

Comment: Your `mode` variable shouldn't be an integer. It should be a `char*`. After you fix that you can compare `if(strcmp(mode, classic) == 0 || strcmp(mode, "Classic") == 0) `.

Comment: @MihaiStancu just to add, and if it a `char *`, memory allocation is required. :)

Comment: Detail: "Strings in C are pointers to... " is not so. in C, strings are not pointers.  Better to think a _string_  is an array with a null character.  "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."

Comment: @chux it's a `char *` and it's treated differently than a plain old pointer to an array because it's not a pointer to an array of particular length but a pointer to the first character in that array and because `string` functions look for that terminator `\0` but in essence they're pointers.

Comment: Identifying a _string_ as a pointer or `char *` is inconsistent with the quote "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters..." which is from the C spec.  The parameters of various string functions like `strcpy(s1, s2)` use "the string pointed to by `s2`".  `s2` is not a string, but it points to one.

Comment: @chux the wording in the standard is correct and refers to the actual *string* data which can even be used as constants from the read-only memory of the program without any malloc -- but which are usually used via a handler pointer such as the `char *`. I changed the wording to better reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look on variable types before.

You're declaring an

```
int mode;
```

which means that in this mode variable, the compiler is waiting for some digits. 
In other words,

```
mode = 5; // correct
mode = "Foobar" // incorrect (compiler error)
```

You have to declare your mode variable as a char *

```
char *mode;
```

Which means that mode now, contains more than 1 char (one character).

Then, to compare the input, with your Classic or Advanced strings
You've got to do it this way

```
if (strcmp(mode, "Classic") == 0) //Since the strcmp function returns 0 if the strings matchs
{
  //Classic Mode
}
else if (strcmp(mode, "Advanced") == 0)
{
  //Advanced Mode
}
else
 printf("Please use Classic or Advanced\n");
```

Comment: Well, when i use this piece of code the program immediately after the question, crashes... Any idea why?

Comment: what does the compiler says ?

Comment: Nothing, it was compiling just fine, and then the crash, but i fixed already, i  was declaring as Mihai said (`char *mode`), when i changed to `char mode[50]` it worked just fine!

Comment: Yes, because you had to allocate it before.

Comment: Yeah, Mihai said it in his answer but i don't think dinamic allocation is needed in such a small program, so i didn't used it, that yesterday, i came back to work today and completely forgot about it and was searching for a goddamn error in the code haha

Answer (score 0):

I will not try to explain more than it was already explained, instead I will show you to possible ways with strcmp and strcasecmp.

For strcmp you need string.h:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char mode[256];

    printf("\n Pick the desired mode: ");
    if((scanf("%s",mode) != EOF)){
        if(strcmp(mode, "Classic") == 0){
            printf("It worked!\n");
        }

        if(strcmp(mode, "Advanced") == 0){
            printf("It worked!\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output1:

> ```
> ./program
> ```

```
 Pick the desired mode: classic
```

Doesn't worked because strcmp is case sensitive.
Output2:

> ```
> ./program
> ```

```
 Pick the desired mode: Classic
It worked!
```

Worked because i typed Classic instead of classic.

If you do not care about case sensitive, then you need strcasecmp function which you find it in strings.h **not in string.h**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<strings.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char mode[256];

    printf("\n Pick the desired mode: ");
    if((scanf("%s",mode) != EOF)){
        if(strcasecmp(mode, "Classic") == 0){
            printf("It worked!\n");
        }

        if(strcasecmp(mode, "Advanced") == 0){
            printf("It worked!\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> ./program
> ```

```
 Pick the desired mode: classic
It worked!
```